# JSP Custom tag Ajax inconsistency

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp, tags

I have a jsp and custom tag to load that is basically a portion of my html code.  The event that triggers the page to call the custom tag is onclick from a button using ajax to reload it.  The problem I'm having is that when it reaches the custom tag to esentially refresh a portion of my page ( the page has checkboxs on them, one is checked) it doesn't entirely refresh that part of the page because I have checkboxes that would get un-checked on the page.  This is an ajax problem that I'm having. Does anyone know why this is happening??? I have other events such as dropdown box and load the same custom tag and it refreshes the page to include the refresh of the checkboxs. Has someone else run into this before?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a caching problem. You need to put no-cache headers at the top of the JSP page that has the tag in it. That might not fix it completely (as in Internet Explorer will probably still do some quirky things).

```
 response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
 response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
```

To prevent Ajax from doing its own caching despite all of that, you might also want to use POST instead of GET.

EDIT: You can also try adding an extra parameter to your request and make it a timestamp so each request will be seen as unique.

Comment: So, that's sounds like it's the problem but tried with no avail.

Comment: I have to use IE and it's strange because I am using the Ajax.Updater() for mulitple events but in this case it doesn't refresh the Ajax. I've got to be missing something!

Comment: In IE if you have update the page set to 'automatic' rather than 'every visit to the page', I've seen it ignore the cache headers for AJAX. You should try adding a timestamp parameter to the request.

Comment: To the Ajax.Updater()... sorry I'm still fairly new to javaScript. How would I go about adding a time stamp?

Comment: Whatever you do to set the fields or request parameters to send, just add one and set it to (new Date().getTime()). You don't have to read it in your JSP. Its just to trick IE into seeing the request as unique.